# Android Image Slider cannot hide page indicator

Tags: android, slideshow, android-image

I am using [daimajia/AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library, I need to display my images without PageIndicator.

I tried :

`mImageSlider.setIndicatorVisibility(PagerIndicator.IndicatorVisibility.Invisible);`

This got rid of the dots in the indicator, however, the grey rectangle shape inside which the dots used to be, still remain. [image]

I need to get rid of the grey rectangle area, is there a solution?

Comment: Is there a `PagerIndicator.IndicatorVisibility.Gone` option?

Comment: No there isn't. There is only `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`. Moreover, I don't think that  `mSliderImage.setIndicatorVisibility()` is the solution, because, I tried that and it got rid of the dots inside the grey area, but not the grey area itself.

Comment: Are you using this library as a gradle dependency or have you downloaded the source code?

Comment: Gradle. I wrote my own slider class as specified  https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Slider-view and it got rid of the problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing my a custom ImageSlider, as specified [here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Slider-view)
I love this library!

Answer (score 7):

Use DefaultSliderView class instead of TextSliderView class. see example below :

```
DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(this);

                defaultSliderView.image(file_maps.get(images)); // adding images here 

                mDemoSlider.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This
`yourSlidShow.getPagerIndicator().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This helped me, page indicator disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**hope this helps someone in future**
just use DefaultSliderView

```
DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(MainActivity.this);
       defaultSliderView .image(Hash_file_maps.get(name))
                         .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                         .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        sliderLayout.addSlider(defaultSliderView);
```